# NativeScript Android Error

Tags: android, nativescript

Whenever I try to build or run an android project I usually run into this problem.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':processF0F1F2F3F4F5DebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Does anyone know why this problem occurs? I have been trying for a very long time to fix this and I cannot figure out how to do so.

I think this is the build.gradle file. Correct me if I am wrong. Hopefully this helps!

```
 /*
*   Script builds apk in release or debug mode
*   To run: 
*           gradle buildapk -Prelease (release mode)
*           gradle buildapk (debug mode -> default)
*   Options:
*           -Prelease  //this flag will run build in release mode
*           -PksPath=[path_to_keystore_file]
*           -PksPassword=[password_for_keystore_file]
*           -Palias=[alias_to_use_from_keystore_file]
*           -Ppassword=[password_for_alias]
*
*           -PtargetSdk=[target_sdk]
*           -PbuildToolsVersion=[build_tools_version]
*           -PsupportVersion=[support_version]
*           -PcompileSdk=[compile_sdk_version]

*           -PdontRunSbg=[true/false]
*/

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper //used to parse package.json
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

def isWinOs = System.properties['os.name'].toLowerCase().contains('windows')
def metadataParams = new LinkedList <String> ()
def allJarPaths = new LinkedList <String> ()
def configurationsDir = "$projectDir/configurations"
def createPluginConfigFile = false
def configStage = "\n:config phase: "
def nodeModulesDir = "../../node_modules/"
def libDir = "$projectDir/../../lib/Android/"
def flavorNames = new ArrayList<String>()
def configDir = file(configurationsDir)

def packageJsonContents = [:]
def excludedDevDependencies = ['**/.bin/**']

def dontRunSbg = project.hasProperty("dontRunSbg");
def asbgProject = project(":asbg")
asbgProject.ext.outDir = new File("$projectDir", "src/main/java")
asbgProject.ext.jsCodeDir = new File("$projectDir", "src/main/assets/app")

def compiteCompileSdkVersion () {
    if(project.hasProperty("compileSdk")) {
        return compileSdk
    }
    else {
        return 23
    }
}

def computeTargetSdkVersion() {
    if(project.hasProperty("targetSdk")) {
        return targetSdk
    }
    else {
        return 23
    }
}

def computeBuildToolsVersion() {
    if(project.hasProperty("buildToolsVersion")) {
        return buildToolsVersion
    }
    else {
        return "23.0.3"
    }
}
project.ext.selectedBuildType = project.hasProperty("release") ? "release" : "debug"

def renameResultApks (variant) {
    def name
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        def apkDirectory = output.packageApplication.outputFile.parentFile
        def apkNamePrefix = rootProject.name + "-" + variant.buildType.name

        if (output.zipAlign) {
            name = apkNamePrefix + ".apk"
            output.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
        }

        name = apkNamePrefix + "-unaligned.apk"
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
    }    
}

// gets the devDependencies declared in the package.json and excludes them from the build
task getDevDependencies << {
    println "$configStage getDevDependencies"
    
    String content = new File("$projectDir/../../package.json").getText("UTF-8")
    def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def packageJsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(content)
    
    packageJsonContents = packageJsonMap.devDependencies;
    
    packageJsonContents.each { entry ->
        excludedDevDependencies.add(entry.key + '/platforms/android/**/*.jar')
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// CONFIGURATIONS ///////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

android {
    compileSdkVersion compiteCompileSdkVersion()
    buildToolsVersion computeBuildToolsVersion()
    
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
    }
    
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir "$projectDir/libs/jni"
    }
    
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if(project.hasProperty("release")) {
                if(project.hasProperty("ksPath") &&
                    project.hasProperty("ksPassword") &&
                    project.hasProperty("alias") &&
                    project.hasProperty("password"))
                {
                    storeFile file(ksPath)
                    storePassword ksPassword
                    keyAlias alias
                    keyPassword password
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        renameResultApks(variant)
    }
    
    
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def compileSourcesTaskName = "compile${variantName}Sources"
        def compileSourcesTask = project.tasks.findByName(compileSourcesTaskName)
        
        def generateBuildConfigTask = variant.generateBuildConfig;
        generateBuildConfigTask.finalizedBy(collectAllJars)
        if(!dontRunSbg) {
            collectAllJars.finalizedBy(setProperties)
        }
        
        compileSourcesTask.finalizedBy(buildMetadata)
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    // used for local *.AAR files
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs/aar'
    }
}

dependencies {
    def suppotVer = "22.2.0";
    if(project.hasProperty("supportVersion")) {
        suppotVer = supportVersion
    }
    
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$suppotVer"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$suppotVer"

    // take all jars within the libs dir
    compile fileTree(dir: "$projectDir/libs", include: ["**/*.jar"])

    // take all jars within the node_modules dir
    compile fileTree(dir: nodeModulesDir, include: ["**/platforms/android/**/*.jar"], exclude: excludedDevDependencies)

    
    //when gradle has aar support this will be preferred instead of addAarDependencies
    // compile files("$rootDir/libs/aar") {
        // builtBy 'copyAarDependencies'
    // }
    
    compile project(':runtime')
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// CONFIGURATION PHASE //////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task pluginStructureCheck {
    def ft = fileTree(dir: nodeModulesDir, include: ["**/platforms/android/**/*.*"], exclude: '**/.bin/**')
    ft.files.each { f ->
        def fileName = f.getName();
        if(
                !fileName.endsWith(".aar")
                &&
                !fileName.equals("include.gradle")
                &&
                !fileName.endsWith(".jar")
            ){
            println "WARNING: The file: " + f + " is depricated, you can read more about what will be the expected plugin structure here: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-n-android-plugins-from-version-1.7-to-2.0" 
        }
    }
}

def updateProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimensionName, oldContent) {
    def endIndex = oldContent.length() - 1;
        def index = 0;
        def newContent = "";
        def level = -1;
        def dimensionFound = false;

        while(index <= endIndex) {
            if(level == 0 && (oldContent[index] == '"' || oldContent[index] == "'")) {
                def closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf('"', index + 1);
                if(closingQuotes == -1) {
                    closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf("'", index + 1);
                }

                index = closingQuotes + 1;
                newContent += "\"${flavor}\"";
                continue;
            }

            if(oldContent[index] == "{") {
                level++;    
            }

            if(oldContent[index] == "}") {
                level--;
            }

            if(level > 0) {
                if(!dimensionFound && oldContent.indexOf("dimension", index) == index) {
                    newContent += "dimension \"${dimensionName}\"";
                    dimensionFound = true;
                    index += "dimension ".length();
                    def openingQuoutes = oldContent.indexOf('"', index);
                    if(openingQuoutes == -1) {
                        openingQuoutes = oldContent.indexOf("'", index);
                    }

                    def closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf('"', openingQuoutes + 1);
                    if(closingQuotes == -1) {
                        closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf("'", openingQuoutes + 1);
                    }   

                    index = closingQuotes + 1;
                }
            }

            newContent += oldContent[index];

            index++;
        }

        return newContent;
}

def createProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimensionName, includeAndroidContent = true)
{
    if (includeAndroidContent)
    {
        def content = """
android {
    productFlavors {
        "${flavor}" {
            dimension "${dimensionName}"
        }
    }
}
"""
        return content;
    }
    else
    {
        def content = """
    productFlavors {
        "${flavor}" {
            dimension "${dimensionName}"
        }
    }
"""
      return content;
    }
}

def createIncludeFile (filePath, flavor, dimensionName) {
    println "\t + creating include.gradle file for ${filePath}" 
    
    def defaultIncludeFile = new File(filePath, "include.gradle")
    defaultIncludeFile.text =  createProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimensionName);
}

def sanatizeDimensionName(str) {
    return str.replaceAll(/\W/, "")
}

def replaceProductFlavorInContent(content, dimension, flavor)
{
    def indexStart = content.indexOf("productFlavors");
    def index = indexStart  + "productFlavors".length();
    def indexEnd = -1;
    def nestedOpenBraketsCount = 0;

    while (index < content.length())
    {
        // print content[index];
        if (content[index] == "}")
        {
            nestedOpenBraketsCount--;

            if (nestedOpenBraketsCount == 0)
            {
                indexEnd = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (content[index] == "{")
        {
            nestedOpenBraketsCount++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    if (indexEnd != -1)
    {
        // full content of productFlavors { ... } -> the substring is parenthesis to parenthesis -> { ... }
      def oldProductFlavorsText = content.substring(indexStart, indexEnd + 1);

      def newProductFlavorsContent = updateProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimension, oldProductFlavorsText);
      
      return content.replace(oldProductFlavorsText, newProductFlavorsContent);
    }
    else
    {
        def androidContentExists = content.indexOf("android {") != -1;
        def newProductFlavorsContent = createProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimension, !androidContentExists);
        
        if (androidContentExists)
        {
           return content.replace("android {", "android { ${newProductFlavorsContent}");
        }
        else
        {
           return "${newProductFlavorsContent} \t ${content}"
        }
    }
}
//make sure the include.gradle file, produced by the user, has only allowed characters in dimension attribute and remove any invalid characters if necessary
def updateIncludeGradleFile(targetFile, dimensionName, flavor)
{
    def fileEntry = new File(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
    def content = fileEntry.text;
    def replacedContent = replaceProductFlavorInContent(content, dimensionName, flavor);
    fileEntry.text = replacedContent;
}

def renamePluginDirToFlavorName(directory, flavor) 
{
    def parentName = directory.getName();
    def parentFile = new File("src", parentName);
    if (parentFile.exists())
    {
        def targetDirName = new File("src", flavor);
        println "Renaming plugin directory to flavor name: ${parentFile.getAbsolutePath()} -> ${targetDirName.getAbsolutePath()}";
        parentFile.renameTo(targetDirName);
    }    
}

def flavorNumber = 0

task createDefaultIncludeFiles {
    description "creates default include.gradle files for added plugins IF NECESSARY"
    println "$configStage createDefaultIncludeFiles"
    def ft = file(configurationsDir)
        
    ft.listFiles().each { fl ->
    
        if(fl.isDirectory()) {
            def fileName = fl.name
            def dimensionName = sanatizeDimensionName(fileName)
            createPluginConfigFile = true
            def foundIncludeFile = false
            
            def flavor = "F" + flavorNumber++
            println "\t+found plugins: " + fileName
            fl.listFiles().each { subFile ->
            
                if(subFile.name == "include.gradle") {
                    foundIncludeFile = true
                    updateIncludeGradleFile(subFile, dimensionName, flavor)
                                        renamePluginDirToFlavorName(subFile.getParentFile(), flavor);
                }
            }
            
            flavorNames.add('"' + dimensionName + '"')
            
            if(!foundIncludeFile) {
                createIncludeFile(fl.getAbsolutePath() , flavor, dimensionName)
                renamePluginDirToFlavorName(fl, flavor);
            }
        }
    }
}

task createPluginsConfigFile {
    description "creates product flavor config file based on what plugins are added"
    
    if(configDir.exists()) {
        println "$configStage createPluginsConfigFile"
        
        def flavorsFile = new File("$configurationsDir/include.gradle")

        if(createPluginConfigFile) {
            println "\t Creating product flavors include.gradle file in $configurationsDir folder..."
            def flavors = flavorNames.join(", ")
            
            def content = """
android {
    flavorDimensions ${flavors}
}
"""
            
            flavorsFile.text =  content
        }
    }
}

task pluginExtend {
    description "applies additional configuration"

    def pathToAppGradle = "$projectDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle" 
    def appGradle = file(pathToAppGradle)
    if(appGradle.exists()) {
        apply from: pathToAppGradle
    }

    if(configDir.exists()) {
    println "$configStage pluginExtend"
        configDir.eachFileRecurse(groovy.io.FileType.FILES) {
            if(it.name.equals('include.gradle')) {
                println "\t+applying configuration from: " + it
                apply from: it
            }
        }
    }
}

//// doesn't work unless task is explicitly called (TODO: research configurations hook)
// addAarDependencies.dependsOn(copyAarDependencies)
// createDefaultIncludeFiles.dependsOn(addAarDependencies)
// createPluginsConfigFile.dependsOn(createDefaultIncludeFiles)
// pluginExtend.dependsOn(createPluginsConfigFile)


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// BEFORE EXECUTION /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// we need to copy all dependencies into a flat dir, as pointed by the repositories configurations at the top
task copyAarDependencies (type: Copy) {
    println "$configStage copyAarDependencies"
    from fileTree(dir: nodeModulesDir, include: ["**/*.aar"], exclude: '**/.bin/**').files
    into "$projectDir/libs/aar"
}

task addAarDependencies <<  {
    println "$configStage addAarDependencies"
    // manually traverse all the locally copied AAR files and add them to the project compilation dependencies list
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: "$projectDir/libs/aar", include: ["**/*.aar"])
    tree.each { File file ->
        // remove the extension of the file (.aar)
        def length = file.name.length() - 4
        def fileName = file.name[0..<length]
        println "\t+adding dependency: " + file.getAbsolutePath()
        project.dependencies.add("compile", [name: fileName, ext: "aar"])
    }
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// EXECUTUION PHASE /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task cleanLocalAarFiles(type: Delete) {
    delete fileTree(dir: "$projectDir/libs/aar", include: ["*.aar"])
}

task ensureMetadataOutDir {
    def outputDir = file("$projectDir/metadata/output/assets/metadata")
    outputDir.mkdirs()
}

task collectAllJars {
    description "gathers all paths to jar dependencies before building metadata with them"
    
    def explodedAarDir = project.buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/intermediates/exploded-aar/"
    def sdkPath = android.sdkDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
    def androidJar = sdkPath + "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"
    
    doFirst {
        configurations.compile.each { File dependencyFile ->
            // println "\t+" + dependencyFile.getAbsolutePath()
            allJarPaths.add(dependencyFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }
        
        allJarPaths.add(androidJar);
        
        def ft = fileTree(dir: explodedAarDir, include: "**/*.jar")
        ft.each { currentJarFile ->
            allJarPaths.add(currentJarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }
        
        metadataParams.add("metadata-generator.jar")
        metadataParams.add("$projectDir/metadata/output/assets/metadata")
        def jars = new LinkedList<File>()
        for(def i = 0; i < allJarPaths.size(); i++) {
            metadataParams.add(allJarPaths.get(i));
            def f = new File(allJarPaths.get(i))
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                jars.add(f)
            }
        }
        asbgProject.ext.jarFiles = jars
    }
}

task buildMetadata (type: JavaExec) {
    description "builds metadata with provided jar dependencies"
    
    inputs.files(allJarPaths)
    inputs.dir("$buildDir/intermediates/classes")

    outputs.files("metadata/output/assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat", "metadata/output/assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat", "metadata/output/assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat")

    doFirst {
        workingDir "build-tools"

        main "-jar"

        // get compiled classes to pass to metadata generator
        // these need to be called after the classes have compiled
        def classesDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/classes"

        def classesSubDirs = new File(classesDir).listFiles()

        def selectedBuildType = project.ext.selectedBuildType

        for (File subDir: classesSubDirs) {
            if (!subDir.getName().equals(selectedBuildType)) {
                def subDirBuildType = new File(subDir, selectedBuildType)
                if (subDirBuildType.exists()) {
                    metadataParams.add(subDirBuildType.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }

        def classesDirBuildType = new File(classesDir, selectedBuildType)
        if (classesDirBuildType.exists()) {
            metadataParams.add(classesDirBuildType.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        args metadataParams.toArray()
    }
    
    doLast {
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/metadata/output/assets/metadata"
            into "$projectDir/src/main/assets/metadata"
        }
        
        def files = new File("${buildDir}/intermediates/res").listFiles()
        def tmpResourceAPK = null
        for (File f: files) {
            def name = f.getName();
            if (name.endsWith(".ap_")) {
                tmpResourceAPK = f;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        def aaptCommand = "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}/build-tools/${android.buildToolsVersion}/aapt"
        if (isWinOs) {
            aaptCommand += ".exe"
        }
        
        def tmpAPKPath = tmpResourceAPK.getPath()
        
        def removeCmdParams = new ArrayList<String>([aaptCommand, "remove", tmpAPKPath, "assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat", "assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat", "assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat"])
        
        exec {
            ignoreExitValue true
            workingDir "$projectDir/metadata/output"
            commandLine removeCmdParams.toArray()
        }
        
        def addCmdParams = new ArrayList<String>([aaptCommand, "add", tmpAPKPath, "assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat", "assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat", "assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat"])
        
        exec {
            workingDir "$projectDir/metadata/output"
            commandLine addCmdParams.toArray()
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// OPTIONAL TASKS //////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
task setProperties {
    project.ext.jarFiles = []
    doLast {
        def list = [];
        allJarPaths.each({f -> 
            if(f.endsWith(".jar")) {
                list.add(f);
            }
        })
        project.jarFiles = list;
    }
} 

setProperties.finalizedBy("asbg:generateBindings")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// EXECUTION ORDER /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// -- configuration phase
// 1. Copy *.aar dependencies
// 2. Add *.aar dependencies
// 3. create default include files
// 4. create plugins config file
// 5. plugin extend (apply from include files)

// --execution phase
ensureMetadataOutDir.dependsOn(cleanLocalAarFiles)
collectAllJars.dependsOn(ensureMetadataOutDir)
buildMetadata.dependsOn(collectAllJars)

//DO NOT UNCOMMENT
// mergeAssets.dependsOn(copyMetadata) -> look in CONFIGURATIONS(top) in android.applicationVariants to see how it's done

task buildapk {
    // problem is compile dependencies need to be changed before configuration stage
    // and this is the only way so far
    tasks.copyAarDependencies.execute()
    tasks.addAarDependencies.execute()

    //done to build only necessary apk
    if(project.hasProperty("release")) {
        dependsOn assembleRelease
    }
    else {
        dependsOn assembleDebug
    }
}

//////// custom clean ///////////
task deleteMetadata (type: Delete){
    delete "$projectDir/metadata/output"
}

task deleteFlavors (type: Delete){
    doLast {
        def srcDir = new File("$projectDir/src")
        srcDir.listFiles().each({ f ->
            if(!f.getName().equals("main")) {
                delete f
            }
        })
    }
}

deleteFlavors.dependsOn(deleteMetadata)
clean.dependsOn(deleteFlavors)
```

Comment: looks like a non valid string type in AndroidManifest.xml. There should be an other error message a few lines above of "*What went wrong". Could you post that?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `build -> clean` and also try rebuilding your project. Can you post your `build.gradle` file(s) if that doesn't work?

Comment: Like the entire thing or part of it?

Comment: All of it, `build.gradle` shouldn't be that long. Did cleaning it not work?

Comment: You want the one that has the `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion` etc.

Comment: That's a really weird gradle file, what IDE are you using? Does this problem come up for every project or just this one?

Comment: I am using a cross platform app called nativescript

Comment: I'd say if this problem was happening for every project you make then it's probably a problem with your setup and it might just be easier to uninstall and reinstall and hope for the best. If it's just for this project that I have no clue, sorry.